# Using sympy's latex printing for an arbitary class

Tags: python, latex, sympy

Say I'm building a class and inside it I have a `__repr__` method for printing it. Is there a way of using sympy's latex printing for the `__repr__` output to be rendered?

For a minimal example, consider

```
e1, e2, e3 = sympy.symbols('e_1 e_2 e_3')
class vector:
    def __init__(self, _coordinates, _basis):
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.basis = basis
    def __repr__(self):
        string = ''
        for k in range(len(basis)):
            string += '{}{} + '.format(self.coordinates[k], self.basis[k])
        return string[:-3]
```

In this example, if I make an instance like this: `v = vector([1, 0, 0], [e1, e2, e3])` I would love for `print(v)` to look like $1e_1 + 0e_2 + 0e_3$. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are preserving the zeros required, or is $e_1$` acceptable?

Comment: No, not really. Are you thinking of just printing the sum as a sympy.add?, I can’t do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTeX display of Sympy object in IPython notebook is handled by IPython's `display` module. If an object has a `_repr_latex_()` function defined, when Sympy `init_printing()` is called, IPython will render the LaTeX representation of the object. The below code should be used with IPython. In the latest version of IPython, the `display()` function does not need to be imported. For older versions, we may have to include `from IPython.display import display`.

```
import sympy as s
s.init_printing()

class vector:
    def __init__(self, _coordinates, _basis):
        self.coordinates = _coordinates
        self.basis = _basis
    def __repr__(self):
        string = ''
        for k in range(len(self.basis)):
            string += '{}{} + '.format(self.coordinates[k], self.basis[k])            
        return string[:-3]
    def _repr_latex_(self):
        string = self.__repr__()
        string = '$' + string + '$'
        return string

e1, e2, e3 = s.symbols('e_1 e_2 e_3')
v = vector([1, 0, 0], [e1, e2, e3])
display(v)
```

Comment: I haven’t tried, but if I put ‘s.init_printing(use_latex=True)’ will it print it like in LaTeX just by using the dollar signs?

Comment: It won't. Are you using IPython? If yes then you will have to write another function in your class `_repr_latex_()` in your class. I will update my answer.

Comment: I’ll check it as soon as I can.

Comment: There is no need to call `init_printing` to make `display(v)` work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the restriction against `sympy.add`. Would this suffice?

```
import sympy as sym
import sympy.printing as printing
e1, e2, e3 = sym.symbols('e_1 e_2 e_3')

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, _coordinates, _basis):
        self.coordinates = _coordinates
        self.basis = _basis
    def __repr__(self):
        expr = sum([c*e for c, e in zip(self.coordinates, self.basis)])
        return '${}$'.format(printing.latex(expr))
v = Vector([1, 0, 0], [e1, e2, e3])
print(repr(v))
# $e_{1}$

v = Vector([1, 2, 3], [e1, e2, e3])
print(repr(v))
# $e_{1} + 2 e_{2} + 3 e_{3}$
```